# How to design this database, one to many?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am new to database but have been researching techniques, but not quite clear on the best plan for my DB?

I have a 'index_table'  with the following columns (with about 65,000 rows)

```
dbo.index_table
Line
Locality
Route (unique)
```

I then plan about 65,000 tables with the following columns: (each with about 20-40 rows)

```
dbo.table2,3.4....etc
Route 
Place
Name
Stop
```

My C# web service with find a match between line and locality in the index_table and the result will be the Route. 
I then need to return all matching rows in the other tables.
Basically each table (apart from the index_table) contains stops on a transit route, so I am finding the stops from the Route identifier.

Is this the correct way to design or should I be doing it a different way to ease and performance reasons.

I am a beginner, please be gentle :)

Comment: Are each of table2, table3, table4, table5, ..., table65000 supposed to represent distinct routes?

Comment: I didn't really undertand what is desired, but 65000 tables with identic structure IMHO can't be the right solution, perhaps one table with some additional keyrows

Comment: Hi Yes, each table contains a list of stops on that route, 30-50 for example, and there are about 65,000 routes

Comment: If each table is specific for route why it contains `Route`? That would be correct to have `Route` to distinguish rows that represents different routes in single table (more correct variant in meaning of relations), but you are saying that you have one route per table. Could you add more meaning to the columns (i.e. `Line`, `Locality`, `Route`) and which of those columns you plan to correspond in name of `table2,3,4...`?

Comment: Yes, thinking about it Route in the other tables will be the same for each row. Route is unique code of the transit route. Like 07L_B16_SE for example.
Line is a friendly route name, and locality is a geographic area. So someone would search for Line '12' in Locality 'Alabama' for example which will only return one match - The unique route code.

Comment: Don't even think of introducing 65000 tables.  It's a disaster waiting to occur!  Run now, while you've got some sanity left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see absolutely no need for 65,000 tables. You should read up on [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to understand the principles around having an efficient and organized schema. You would be making your life much harder to try to implement and manage 65,000 tables. A single table that has (65000 * 20-40) 1300000-2600000 rows could be very efficiently managed.

On your `index_table`, when you mean `route`, do you mean a single value? Or will this `route` have more than one value in it?

My thought on the design would be:

**route** (route, line, locality)

**route_stop** (route, place, name, stop)

- `route_stop.route` would be a foreign key to `route.route`
- Since I don't have sample data, your primary key on `route_stop` could be a composite of the columns that make a unique value

Comment: This is an interesting concept. I wasnt sure if say 1 million rows would be excessive rather than thousands of tables with less rows. 
Route is a single value, a unique code like 45B_B16_SE for example

Comment: In this two table design, there would be 20-40 route_stop.route fields that are identical, would that be possible with the foreign key concept?

Comment: @DanSewell Depends. What other attributes would make up a unique way to identify the row in your `route_stop` table?

Answer (score 1):

With 65,000 routes, each with 20-40 stops, you have very little data and are nowhere near the point where a database would die under the weight of a massive table.  (If you had tens of millions of stops you would still be okay with 1-3 tables, using partitioning or sharding and other techniques if necessary).

njk is correct in that if you are one-to-many between routes and stops, you need only a table for routes and a table of stops (+1 to him BTW).

However I cannot imagine that you really have a *one-to-many* scenario here.  In all transit systems I know of, stops are shared between routes, and you would have a *many-to-many* scenario.  I would introduce a primary key `stop_id` for the stops table and then have a join table linking the routes and stops.  The join table will contain a third column for the position of the stop within the route.

So in a relational database: three tables.

```
ROUTE: route_id, line, locality
STOP: stop_id, name, place
ROUTE_STOP: route_id, stop_id, position
```

(Aside: If you have any interest in NoSQL, this would be a really nice application for you to get familiar with a document database, such as MongoDB.  Then you could use a list for each stop and not need a position number to order the stops within a route - which, BTW, and I am "being gentle" :) is something you seem to be lacking in your original question, if I understand it correctly....)

Comment: That could work quite well. I have an existing DB with a table containing 300,000 unique stop nodes rows, which already serves the purpose of your STOP table.

Comment: Oh nice.  I simply guessed that in your question, `Stop` was a string, so you had that part right all along. :)  Maybe the ordering part of the answer was new?

Comment: and yes you are right about transit routes sharing the stops!